# Removing spaces from String using another string

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove spaces from string trying to use the string itself but it is not working at all. On debugging I found out that it was putting in strange value inside the string str1 which I don't understand why it does that. Following is the code attached, what can be the problem? Why is it not working?

```
string str = "Hello World";
string str1 = " ";
int increment = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str[i] == ' ') {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        str1[increment] += str[i];
        increment++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use algorithm functions.  `str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str1[increment]` is UB for any `increment > 0`, since `str1` only has a length of 1. You are also adding the value of a character to each element, not appending a string. Just change

```
str1[increment] += str[i]
```

to

```
str1 += str[i]
```

And change `string str1 = " ";` to `string str1;`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing loops, use the STL algorithm functions to do the erasure.

First, the algorithm functions do not fail if given the proper arguments.

Second, the code itself is basically self-documenting.

For example, if someone were to look at your hand-coded loop, it is not obvious as to what you are trying to accomplish at first glance.  On the other hand, when a C++ programmer sees `std::remove` it is known immediately what it will do.

The STL alogrithm function that would be used is [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), along with using [std::string::erase()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello World";
    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld
```

Comment: `erase(remove(...))` is used so often, this combination [now has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Answer (score -1):

First, here you are increasing the value. Not assigning:

```
str1[increment] += str[i];
```

I think you want to do:

```
str1[increment] = str[i];
```

Since you're declaring str1 as " " you're getting a small buffer so you can't assign something on str[n] for n > 0 in this case. The right way to do it is:

```
string str = "Hello World";
string str1;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    if (str[i] != ' ')
        str1 += str[i];
```

Alternatively, if you really need go the way you're doing, I would recommend to use char* instead of std::string

```
string str = "Hello World";
char str1[str.length()];
int increment = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    if (str[i] != ' ')
        str1[increment++] = str[i];
        
str1[increment] = '\0';
```

At the end, the variable `increment` will be the exact size of `str1`. You can just convert to string at the end with:

```
string s = str1;
```

Comment: `char str1[str.length()]` only works if using the C++ VLA language extension, which is optional - may not work for someone else. Also, it should be `char str1[str.length()] + 1`.

Comment: Actually char `str1[str.length() + 1]`.

Answer (score -1):

it is the code in python:

```
txt = "hello world" spaces = " "

txt = txt.replace(" ", "")


print(txt)
```

you can change it to any language you want.
it removes spaces from a sentence.